# Setting Default Ubuntu eth port

Tags: 12.04, clonezilla

Background:

I have a desktop computer running Ubuntu 12.04.
I have installed DRBL to handle DHCP server and Clonezilla Server.
I have a network card in my desktop with 2 ports in it.
These 2 ports are bonded together and are used by DRBL.
There is a 3rd port integrated in the motherboard.
I want to use this 3rd port for internet.
DRBL knows that this is set for internet.
EDIT: "Ubuntu Network-Manager has stopped recognising the connections (device not managed)." - I have now uninstalled Network-Manager.
It use to say that eth1 was default (first port in the network card)
I want eth0 to be default as that is the Internet port.

Question:

How do I make eth0 as the default port without using Network-Manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to use network manager for default network assignment is by checking the '**Use this connection only for resources on its network**' option in editing IPv4 routes on all connections you do NOT want to be the default.

To do this without Network manager simply edit connections that you don't want to be default and add the following at the end of each corresponding file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YourConnection`

```
never-default=true
```

this line should be added under IPv4 section.

**NOTE**: Replace YourConnection with the corresponding Connection name. You can see available options via

`ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Comment: So would YourConnection be like eth0 if thats my internet port?

Comment: i don't have network-manager

Comment: I have found in NetworkManager.conf that has a line like no-auto-connection=[mac addresses] so i wonder if i can have auto-connection=[mac address] ??

Comment: how do you do it then?

Comment: why, i've asked the question up above, post a new answer!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/196671/how-to-create-a-default-port-which-has-dhcp-set