# How to create a default port which has DHCP set

Tags: 12.04, networking, clonezilla

I have 3 ports configured on my Ubuntu 12.04.

2 are bonded and used for DRBL pxe boot server and Clonezilla

The other one I want as the internet port and is set to DHCP.

How do I get ubuntu to use that port by default so that I can access the internet while I'm clonezillaring?

Thanks,

ifconfig output:

```
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:48:a6:24  
          inet addr:192.168.100.2  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe48:a624/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:423118949 errors:0 dropped:603 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:290641418 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:372054944369 (372.0 GB)  TX bytes:308595651240 (308.5 GB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:69:95:d1:db:ff  
          inet addr:192.168.10.63  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e269:95ff:fed1:dbff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2025 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4094743 (4.0 MB)  TX bytes:265858 (265.8 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fe700000-fe720000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:48:a6:24  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:211494488 errors:0 dropped:245 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:145328734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:185877441115 (185.8 GB)  TX bytes:154310653091 (154.3 GB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fe660000-fe680000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:48:a6:24  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:211624448 errors:0 dropped:358 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:145312672 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:186177502078 (186.1 GB)  TX bytes:154284981451 (154.2 GB)
          Interrupt:17 Memory:fe620000-fe640000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1812 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:131568 (131.5 KB)  TX bytes:131568 (131.5 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`**YourDhcpEthernetPort**
2. under section `[ipv4]`

   change the following `method=manual` to `method=auto` and remove `dns=x.x.x.x` and `addresses=x.x.x.x` if you want automatic dhcp configuration
3. Don't forget to add `never-default=true` for other ports in their corresponding file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

Comment: That is already my configuration, the last person gave the same answer you have . . . .

Comment: ok please post your `ifconfig` output

Comment: see edits up above

Comment: it seems your eth0 is the one connected to the internet and it has an IP. So if you followed my answer this should work for you, Am I right?

Comment: You are correct, but the configuration was already set to what you have said. And then it was not working.

Comment: OK. what's the status now? you cannot connect to the internet? How did your eth0 take an IP? from DHCP?